# How to serve static files in Rails from a mounted path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, assets, rack

I am trying to develop a gem to be used in Rails applications that includes serving static files (html, js, and css) at a mounted location. Using the gem's UI will be accomplished by adding the following to `config/routes.rb`

```rb
mount MyGem::UI.new, at: "/foo"
```

I have this almost working using `Rack::Static`, but am not attached to this solution if there is a better one.

```rb
module MyGem
  module_function

  def root
    @root ||= Pathname(__dir__).expand_path
  end
end
```

```
module MyGem
  class UI
    def call(env)
      static_app.call(env)
    end

    def static_app
      Rack::Static.new(nil, static_options)
    end

    def static_options
      {urls: [""], root: asset_path, index: 'index.html'}
    end

    def asset_path
      @root ||= MyGem.root.join("assets")
    end
  end
end
```

The files at `MyGem.root`/assets can be reduces to a single html file that links to a single css file in the same location using `href="./index.css"`. (In reality they will be a React app built with [`homepage: "./"` in `package.json` using create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/527#issuecomment-244793467) to produce `./` relative links to all assets.) I have tested this setup using both the dummy and the full-fledge React app.

This setup works **if and only if** I go to `localhost:3000/foo/` with the trailing slash. However, if I navigate to `localhost:3000/foo` without the trailing slash, I successfully get the `index.html` page, but all of its links are broken, returning 404 not found:

> GET http://localhost:3000/index.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

How can I avoid this and robustly server my static content at the mounted location, "/foo"? It's halfway acceptable as a pilot to just require the trailing slash, but is a bit dodgy to leave in a published gem.

I am open to solutions involving alternate rails routes configurations, different ways to serve the static content (contingent on being easily describable to gem users), and different ways to build the static content, and anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this through your rails app as serving static content directly with nginx or apache would be so much more performant.

Comment: I'm writing a gem for use in other rails apps, or possibly any ruby project using FactoryBot. So the #1 requirement is that a Rails user can drop this in their gemfile, add some basic configs, and start using it. Similar to the Resque dashboard or Flipper. From what I've seen, those gems serve relatively simple static content and do so by building thw html response directly. Perhaps that will be where this goes, but i already have more complex React-built content that I'm trying to extract into this gem.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use nginx or apache (which is currently the best approach for a lot of very good reasons), there are Ruby application servers that support static content delivery (i.e., iodine or agoo)... having the application layer send the static content is suboptimal and could introduce stress to the server's concurrency logic as well as possible "head of line" issues.

Comment: I must be missing something here, can anyone help me either understand or rephrase my question? My goal is not to spin up a server. It is to make a gem that plugs into existing Rails apps. The static content is one piece of this. Does it make sense to require the developers who use this gem to spin up a new server in parallel with their Rails server to use it? Both Reque and Flipper, as very parallel examples, accomplish this by allowing the user developers to mount a Rack application in their Rails routes file. Is this possible with any of the above solutions?